Springboot with kafka runtime topic and listener
Good morning... does anyone who works with Kafka know if it's possible for me to reproduce the following scenario?
I have a user table with 3 users and I have 3 different processes on my system (A, B and C), so I will have a queue for each process..
Can I create a queue for each process for each user? for example:
Process A for user 1 listening to the queue (process/a/user/1)
Process A for user 2 listening to the queue (process/a/user/2)
Process A for user 3 listening to the queue (process/a/user/3)

Process B for user 1 listening to the queue (process/b/user/1)
Process B for user 2 listening to the queue (process/b/user/2)
Process B for user 3 listening to the queue (process/b/user/3)

Process C for user 1 listening to the queue (process/c/user/1)
Process C for user 2 listening to the queue (process/c/user/2)
Process C for user 3 listening to the queue (process/c/user/3)

and if a new user appears, create 1 more of each for him. and so it goes?? This will be online so I could theoretically add or remove a new user
**Each process are one diferent class
thanks

Isn't it answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563977/can-a-kafka-producer-create-topics-and-partitions ?
